# mdx specification?

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap

I'm looking for the formal specification of MDX. Going via xmla specification site, I found it may be in "OLE DB for OLAP specification" which is supposed to be available from microsoft, but I can't find it on their site anywhere.

Any clues? I'm looking for the structure of MDX queries essentially.

Comment: I got help from this - [mdx functions](http://www.iccube.com/ "mdx functions") Examples of related functions available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found language and statement references:

- [MDX Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145595.aspx)
- [MDX Statement Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145610.aspx)

For example, check this out: [SELECT Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146002.aspx). Not a specification, but should be enough, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the OLE DB for OLAP spec, this is the link:

[MDX Concepts (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719697%28v=vs.85%29)

You'll note that this is quite a bit smaller (and older) than the mainline SQL Server Analysis Services documentation. Strictly speaking, the link above is the "standard". Since then, Microsoft has largely left the standard to languish and chosen to expand on the standard within Analysis Services.

Of late, Redmond's energy has shifted to BISM/DAX so even Analysis Services' MDX has languished.

Comment: I suspect the correct link is [*OLE DB for Online Analytical Processing (OLAP)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717005(v=vs.85).aspx).